# Counting referring rows in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Id | Name                    | Parent
---+-------------------------+-------
1  | Parent One              | 0
2  | Child of Parent One     | 1
3  | Parent Two              | 0
4  | Parent Three            | 0
5  | Parent Four             | 0
6  | Child of 1st Parent     | 1
7  | Child of 2nd Parent     | 3
8  | Child of 3nd Parent     | 4
```

The table does not represent a hierarchy: Every item is either a child or a parent, but not both.

I'd like to run a query on it that returns this:

```
Id | Name                    | ChildCount
---+-------------------------+-----------
1  | Parent One              | 2
3  | Parent Two              | 1
4  | Parent Three            | 1
5  | Parent Four             | 0
```

I guessed that this might work, but it didn't:

```
SELECT parents.id, parents.name, COUNT(parents.id = children.parent) AS childCount
FROM (SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent = 0) parents,
     (SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent > 0) children
```

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.Name, COUNT(b.id) as ChildCount
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON (b.Parent = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id [,a.Name] // ,a.Name is not mandatory for mysql, `GROUP BY a.id` is enough
```

You may also want to add `WHERE a.Parent = 0` to show only parent rows.

**Updated** (`COUNT(*)` changed to `COUNT(b.id)` )

For Eldest Child:

```
SELECT x.id, x.Name, x.ChildCount, c.Name AS eldest_child_name
FROM
(
SELECT a.id, a.Name, COUNT(b.id) as ChildCount, MAX(b.id) as max_child_id
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON (b.Parent = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id 
)X
LEFT JOIN table1 c ON (c.id = X.max_child_id)
```

Comment: is `table1.b` supposed to be `table1 b`?

Comment: @Eric: yeah, sorry for misprint :)

Comment: Yep that works. As a bonus question, what do I have to do to add an `Eldest Child Name` column, where 'Eldest' means 'Highest id'. Can I do it without another join?

Comment: I cannot think about `no-extra-join`(or `no-subquery`) solution for the eldest child name...

Comment: I've added my solution for Eldest Child, it uses extra join; though it might be useful.